# std::condition_variable::wait() misunderstanding

Tags: c++, multithreading, wait

Why is it necessary to use `while()` with  `std::condition_variable::wait()`
in this [code](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/):

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void print_id (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);
  // ...
  std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread threads[10];
  // spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(print_id,i);

  std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
  go();                       // go!

  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

  return 0;
}
```

If, as I understand, `std::condition_variable::wait()` blocks the current thread, and that thread is waiting in the point of suspending until some another thread is calling a notify..() function

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it necessary to use while() with std::condition_variable::wait()

`wait` may return whether `ready` is true or not. If we want to proceed only when `ready` is true, then we must check it, and continue waiting in case it isn't. A loop is a convenient control structure for repeating an operation until a condition is satisfied.

---

> why wait() may return seemingly spuriously

Because the standard says that it may:

> Effects:
>
> - Atomically calls `lock.unlock()` and blocks on *this.
> - When unblocked, calls `lock.lock(` (possibly blocking on the lock), then returns.
> - The function will unblock when signaled by a call to `notify_­one()` or a call to `notify_­all()`, **or spuriously**.

Comment: Isn't that a little reductive? It seems self-evident from the code. I would imagine OP wants to understand why `wait()` may return seemingly spuriously.

Comment: @Frank I added more details.

Comment: I've answered my question. That might be more satisfying - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68776320/14934019

Comment: @MaxPopovsky That answer seems to fail to mention the third case where a thread may be awoken: Spurious wakeups, which may happen without neither of the notification functions being called.

Comment: @eerorika I see Spurious wakeups is implicit thing. Can you advise me an article with clear and not sophisticated explanation of it?

Comment: @MaxPopovsky A clear explanation: Threads may wake up whenever for whatever reason. Solution: Use loop to always check a condition variable.